# Device must shut down after receiving sms

Tags: blackberry, sms

I need help.

I've created a simple app that listens for an incoming sms and when the sms arrives with the word "OFF" then the device should shut down.

The app opens up but fails to shut the device down after receiving an sms with the word "OFF"

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code:

```java
new Thread() { //A new thread is created and surrounds the code 

    public void run() {

        try {

           DatagramConnection _dc =
           (DatagramConnection)Connector.open("sms://"); //A DatagramConnection is created to listen for any incoming sms's.

           for(;;) { //'For-Loop' used to listen continously for incoming sms's

                Datagram d = _dc.newDatagram(_dc.getMaximumLength());                     
                _dc.receive(d);  //The sms is received                           
                byte[] bytes = d.getData();
                String msg = new String(bytes); //The body of the sms is put on a string.

                if (msg == ("OFF") {

                    Device.requestPowerOff(false); //The device is shut down

                }                              
           }  

        } catch (NullPointerException me) { //NullPointerException caught       
              me.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException io) {
              io.printStackTrace(); 
        }        
    }
};
```

When I run the app without the thread, it freezes the phone.

Please help, I've tried everthing I know but can't seem to get it right.

Comment: If you're using Java shouldn't you be using msg.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")? Also inside the "if" block where you're requesting the shutdown you might want to break out of it.

Comment: It doesn't have anything to do with the string, I think it's something with the thread.

Comment: new Thread() { //A new thread is created and surrounds the code 
        
public void run() {
            
            try {
        Device.requestPowerOff(false); //The device is shut down
                                           
              }  
                                        
              } catch (NullPointerException me) { //NullPointerException caught       
                    me.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException io) {
                    io.printStackTrace(); 
    }        
    }
    };

Comment: When I run the above code without the thread, the device shuts down correctly, but as soon as I run it inside the thread the app doesn't work.

Comment: Try _dc.close() just before you request the shutdown.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but still the same effect

Comment: In the question, you say that when you run the app without the thread, it freezes the phone.  Then, in a comment above, you say that when you run the code without the thread, it shuts down correctly.  Which is it?